# Javascript change style where style equals something

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to add some style properties on an image but only if it already contains another property. I have more or less figure out how to do this with the following:

```
if ($('#content p img').css('float') == 'right')
    $('#content p img').css('margin-left', '20px').css('margin-bottom', '20px');
```

But this obviously changes all images so they have margin left and bottom. How can I do the same but only add the margin to the images that has the `float: right;` property?

Comment: I've added the `jquery` tag, as it looks like you're using `jquery` (and it matters to the answers people give)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('#content p img').filter(function() {
    return this.style.float === "right";
}).css('margin-left', '20px').css('margin-bottom', '20px');
```

And you can call [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) just once if you like, passing in a set of changes to make:

```
$('#content p img').filter(function() {
    return this.style.float === "right";
}).css({
    'margin-left':   '20px',
    'margin-bottom': '20px'
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I will mark your answer correct in 11 minutes. =)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('#content p img').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('float') == 'right') 
        $(this).css('margin-left', '20px').css('margin-bottom', '20px');
})
```